# isuue with iotedge send confirmation callback

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am sending telemetry data from iotedge module to azure cloud and I need to confirm that the data is received at cloud. Found that I can use confirmation callback for it.

This is how I send data:

```
clientResult = IoTHubModuleClient_LL_SendEventToOutputAsync(iotHubModuleClientHandle, messageInstance->messageHandle, "output1", SendConfirmationCallback_dps, (void *)messageInstance);
```

And this is my callback function:

```
void SendConfirmationCallback_dps(IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONFIRMATION_RESULT result, void* userContextCallback)
{

    printf("Confirmation[%zu] received for message with result = %d\r\n", messageInstance->messageTrackingId, result);
}
```

**Question:
Will I get an error response if the network is not available while sending data?
Am I missing anything that required to achieve for my purpose? My code is working well in all other aspects.
**

**My issue:**
**The 'result' variable that comes in confirmation callback is equal to zero ("IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONFIRMATION_OK") even if there is no network while sending data.**

*Board specs:
C SDK,
iotedge V1.0.8,
Ubuntu 18.04,
ARM32*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send telemetry data from your module to IoT Hub, you’re actually sending it to Edge Hub—another local module that acts as a proxy to IoT Hub and allows clients to continue operating offline. The Edge Hub will then forward your data on to the cloud as soon as it can. So the success result you’re seeing means the data was sent to Edge Hub. Your data will make it to the cloud, but there’s no built-in way to get a confirmation callback from the cloud in that scenario.